# Kastrel tuning for large (>1MB) response json

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have .net core MVC API implementation. In my controller I try to query for 800 records from DB. In result my response body size is abound 6MB. In that case response time is over 6s. My service is in AWS cloud.
I made several tests to make diagnostic of service. In all these scenarios I still ready 800 records from DB. Here is list of my experiments:

1. Return only 10 records - my response time were **under 800ms** always and size of response body 20kB.
2. Return only 100 records - my response time were **over 800ms** but not timeouts and size of response body 145kB
3. Try to use my custom json serialization in controller `await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(HttpContext.Response.Body, limitedResult);` - a bit better result but like 10% only
4. Return only 850 records - my response time were **over 6s** but and size of response body 6MB

In service I don't have problem with memory or with restart service.
Looks like for Kastrel the problem is to serve large response data.
My objections are connected with buffers I/O which for large response will use disk what can affect performance of AWS docker image.
Question is how to optimize Kastrel to serve large response size?

UPDATE:
I enabled zip compression on server side. My files are compressed quite good because of json format. But result is exact the SAME. Network bandwidth is not a problem. So looks like between my controller and compression is bottleneck. Any suggestion how to configure .net core service to handle large response (>1 MB)?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the default JSON serializer used in .NET (Core) is around 3 to 4 times slower than NewtonSoft Json. I'm working with responses of 50+MB and managed to decrease my response times drastically using this approach.

You can test it real quickly by changing the response type of your controller action to System.IO.Stream, and manually serialize your respons at the bottom of your controller like this (I used a specific instance of the DefaultContrectResolver in order to maintain the casing strategy of the default JSON deserializer in .NET):

```
            Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = contractResolver,
                Formatting = Formatting.None
            });
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already sure that network is not an issue - this mostly points to time being spent in serialization. You can try running the application on local machine and using a profiler such as [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) to see where the time is spent most for big json.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made test that I make manual json serialization to memory stream for whole result, next I only serialize 10 records to `HttpContext.Response.Body`. So in consequence I serialize 850+10 but send very small response. In that case service is working fine. Any other idea?